# copyWithZone using mogenerator

Tags: ios, objective-c, mogenerator, copywithzone

I'm using Mogenerator to generate my models. So in my Human model I have

```
- (id)copyWithZone:(NSZone *)zone
{
    AppointmentGrid *appointmentGridCopy = [[[self class] allocWithZone:zone] init];
    [appointmentGridCopy setEmployeeId:self.employeeId];
    [appointmentGridCopy setEmployeeObject:self.employeeObject];
    [appointmentGridCopy setServiceId:self.serviceId];
    [appointmentGridCopy setServiceObject:self.serviceObject];
    [appointmentGridCopy setStartTimestamp:self.startTimestamp];
    [appointmentGridCopy setEndTimestamp:self.endTimestamp];
    [appointmentGridCopy setAppointmentGridSlots:self.appointmentGridSlots];

    return appointmentGridCopy;
}
```

Since the Machine class has all the properties I haven't readded them into the Human file. However I get an error

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[AppointmentGrid setEmployeeId:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

Do I really need to redefine everything in my Human file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instances of `NSManagedObject` *must be* created using the designated initialiser

```
initWithEntity:insertIntoManagedObjectContext:
```

The Core Data property accessor methods are created dynamically at runtime, and that
cannot work if the object was created with a plain `init` method.

This might work (untested):

```
AppointmentGrid *appointmentGridCopy = [[[self class] allocWithZone:zone] 
    initWithEntity:self.entity
    insertIntoManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
```

Comment: ahh yes... completely spaced on that part! ty

Comment: as a side note you need to create in the same context or you cannot copy relationships without manual work.

Comment: @Bot: You are welcome. (Note that this is a runtime exception and is therefore unrelated to mogenerator, which only creates the source code.)